# OAuth generate signature

Tags: android, hash, oauth, signature

I am trying to generate the signature for the OAuth request. Here is how I do it:

```
String toHash = URLEncoder.encode("POST&https://" + url + "&oauth_callback=oob&oauth_consumer_key=" + key + "&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=" + timeStamp + "&oauth_nonce=" + timeStamp);

String hash = computeHmac(toHash, secret);
```

...

```
public String computeHmac(String baseString, String key)
    {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), mac.getAlgorithm());
        mac.init(secret);
        byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(baseString.getBytes());
        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(digest));
    }
```

But the server tells me that the signature is wrong. What am I am doing wrong? Pease help...

Answer (score 3):

According to the OAuth specification:

> The signature base string is constructed by concatenating together,
> in order, the following HTTP request elements:
>
> 1. The HTTP request method in uppercase.  For example: "HEAD",
>    "GET", "POST", etc.  If the request uses a custom HTTP method, it
>    MUST be encoded (Section 3.6).
> 2. An "&" character (ASCII code 38).
> 3. The base string URI from Section 3.4.1.2, after being encoded
>    (Section 3.6).
> 4. An "&" character (ASCII code 38).
> 5. The request parameters as normalized in Section 3.4.1.3.2, after
>    being encoded (Section 3.6).

In your base string some chars are not correctly encoded and normalized. For instance:

```
https://             ->   https%3A%2F%2F
oauth_callback=oob   ->   oauth_callback%3Doob
...
```

All details about the string construction are here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4.1.1

Comment: Thanks for your help. The combined instructions on teh internetz are still woefully unclear about what gets normalized, what gets encoded and in what order. For instance; why are some of the '&' characters encoded and some not... OAuth, I would spit my last breath at thee...